# Git fast-import didn't preserve the line endings

Tags: git, git-fast-import

I'm Migrating a StarTeam repository to Git through the use of Git's fast-import command and StarTeam's SDK. All the work is occurring on Windows. Though most of the files were in a Windows format (CRLF), there were 2 that were in a UNIX style (LF). In my first attempt those two files had their LF converted to CRLF.

The problem ended up being that I had core.autocrlf set to true. Once I removed that global setting, and reran the import, the 2 files preserved their original EOL format.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should post it as an answer (instead of editing the question).  You can then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being that I had core.autocrlf set to true. Once I removed that global setting, and reran the import, the 2 files preserved their original EOL format.